# Inno Setup custom form is hiding beneath installation page

Tags: inno-setup

We are showing custom form during [Run] section in interactive installation. But custom form is hiding beneath installation page. Is any way to show the custom form on installer like message boxes.

Using below code to create custom form. and calling it in [Run] section.

```
[Setup]
AppId=Display Form
AppName=Display Form
DefaultDirname={sd}\Test
DisableDirPage=yes
WindowVisible=no
OutputDir=C:\Test
[Run]
Filename: C:\Test.exe; Flags: runhidden; AfterInstall : PassphraseForm;
[Code]
Procedure PassphraseForm();
var
  Form: TSetupForm;
  OKButton: TNewButton;
  mLabel:TLabel;
  LogFileString : AnsiString;
  RichEditViewer: TRichEditViewer;
  cancelclick: Boolean;
begin

Form := CreateCustomForm();
try
Form.ClientWidth := ScaleX(400);
Form.ClientHeight := ScaleY(180);
Form.Caption := 'Server';
Form.Center
mLabel:=TLabel.Create(Form);
mLabel.Caption:='';
mLabel.AutoSize:=True;
mLabel.Alignment:=taCenter;

OKButton := TNewButton.Create(Form);
OKButton.Parent := Form;
OKButton.Width := ScaleX(70);
OKButton.Height := ScaleY(30);
OKButton.Left := ScaleX(170);
OKButton.Top := ScaleY(142);
OKButton.Caption := 'OK';
OKButton.ModalResult := mrOk;

RichEditViewer :=TRichEditViewer.Create(Form);
RichEditViewer.Width :=360;
RichEditViewer.Height :=120;
RichEditViewer.Top := 20;
RichEditViewer.Left :=20;
RichEditViewer.Alignment:=taLeftJustify;
RichEditViewer.Parent := Form;
RichEditViewer.WordWrap :=True;
RichEditViewer.ScrollBars := ssBoth;
RichEditViewer.UseRichEdit := True;
RichEditViewer.Font.Size:=9;
RichEditViewer.RTFText := 'Server Value'; 

RichEditViewer.ReadOnly := True;
Form.ActiveControl := OKButton;
cancelclick:=True;
if Form.ShowModal() = mrOk then
begin
  Log('Custom form is displayed succesfully');
end;
finally
Form.Free();
end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you paste whole code? This is just creating of the form/ [Run] section usually cannot show forms - that should be done in [Code] section.

Comment: Slappy: I have updated whole code, Can you check Now?

Answer (score 0):

*OK, this is really nice (undocumented) feature of Inno Setup!
I had no idea [Run] section support AfterInstall parameter (it is not mentioned in manual :)*

Anyway your code works fine for me: [image: picture]

I think there is no way displaying the form below the main form as it is created as Modal form and shown with **Form.ShowModal()**.

*Are you sure the form is not displayed somewhere else? E.g. on second monitor/screen or outside of screen borders?
Also check the debugger - maybe a breakpoint was hit just when form is about to show and you need to press F9 to continue.*

Comment: Slappy: We are displaying the form in center of installer. We are hitting this issue(form is hiding beneath installer page) only when user switches to another session and comes back when installation is going on. If he stays on same session, form is displayed as a model form.